# paypal Javascript Integration - What's form Action Parameter?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

What is "/checkout" in the below line ?. Actually it referring localpath.
Can you please suggest me the appropriate action URL ?

Also, Can you suggest me where do I give the IPN URL / Syntax ?

```
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="/checkout"></form>

 <script>
  window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
    paypal.checkout.setup('<Your-Merchant-ID>', {
        environment: 'sandbox',
        container: 'myContainer'
      });
  };
</script>
```

[paypal Integration] https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 0):

This describes it:

> A basic Express Checkout integration assumes that you are sending the
>   API calls from **your own server** using a `<form>` or `<a>`.

Essentially, your *existing* call to `SetExpressCheckout` (that would obtain a Paypal `token`) that you use to `redirect` (in the "standard" Paypal Express Checkout flow).

The [linked sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfNSVRyq86pDR5mH4HH?p=preview) should hopefully clear things up - you'll see the `form` action (and `a` link) `POST` (`GET` for the `a`) to some **server implementation** (the ip address in the sample) of `SetExpressCheckout`.

Hth..

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with single page PayPal pay now button actually I use this one of my projects

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</script> 

<div id="paypal-button-container"> </div>


<script>
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '1230'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      alert('Transaction completed');
      // Call your server to save the transaction
      return fetch('codes/paypalapi.php?invo=123', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          orderID: data.orderID,
          amount: data.amount
        })         
      });
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

change `codes/paypalapi.php?invo=123` with your callback url